# Getting error on deploying nestjs app on gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nestjs

Getting error on deploying nestjs app on google app engine. The deployment worked fine but app is giving error[image]

Here is the my **package.json** file

```js
"main": "dist/main.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node ./dist/main.js",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "build": " tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "gcp-build": "npm run build"
  },
```

and this my **app.yaml** file

```js
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard
```

I tried to see the error on gcloud console by gcloud app logs read and it gives me error in cjs/loader file
[image]

The app is working fine locally. Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error: Cannot find module 'src/utils'`

It looks like you are using non-relative imports and using `src` as a root, which won't work once you have transpiled from typescript to javaScript without some extra modifications. The `src` directory shouldn't exist when you are in your production environment, only the `dist` that has your JavaScript. If you change the import to be a relative one (using `..` to get tot the correct directory from where you are) it should work just fine